# Find all entities with dates between, spring data jpa

Tags: spring, date, jpa

I have this entity:

```
public class Tender {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Long id;
private String source;
private String sourceRefNumber;
private String link;
private String title;
@Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
private String description;
private String field;
private String client;
private String type;
private Date date;
private Date deadline;
@ManyToMany
private List<Cpv> cpv;}
```

And for this following interface:

```
public interface TenderRepository extends JpaRepository<Tender, Long> {

List<Tender> findAllByDateGreaterThanEqualAndDateLessThanEqual(Date start, Date end);

List<Tender> findAllByDateBetween(Date start, Date end);}
```

I use this interface in my Service and ServiceImpl.
In my Resource I have method:

```
@GetMapping("/listforperiod/{start}/{end}")
public ResponseEntity<List<Tender>> getTendersForPeriod(@PathVariable("start")
                                                        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date start,
                                                        @PathVariable("end")
                                                        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date end) {
    List<Tender> list = tenderService.findAllByDateBetween(start, end);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(list, OK);}
```

I have tried both findAllByDateBetween and findAllByDateGreaterThanEqualAndDateLessThanEqual - both return 0 records, but in database I see all of them:
[image]

Where can be a problem?

Comment: What are the `start` and `end` dates used ? If they are the same (e.g. 2022-08-01), you will only find the records having a date at 2022-08-01T00:00:00.

Comment: @Julien I tried few dates that should fit to records from base, inclusive and exclusive - in any case I get 0 records back.

Comment: Make sure that your `start` and `end` strings are parsed to correct date, and JPA query finally translated to a correct native SQL. Also there might be an issue because you are using obsolete class `java.util.Date`. I suggest to try with  `java.time.LocalDate` (and others from `java.time.*` package)

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko thank you and v.ladynev for pointing to java.util.Date issues - I changed all date fields to LocalDate and now I can use spring jpa findAllByDateGreaterThanEqualAndDateLessThanEqual method. But it working strangely with 1 day offset, so to get real records I should use findAllByDateGreaterThanEqualAndDateLessThanEqual(start.plusDays(1), end.plusDays(1)